# How can I update date using Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, laravel-6

How can I update the date using Datepicker? This is how I create the Datepicker below.

```html
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '-100y:c+nn',
            maxDate: '1d'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Please try with below code.

`<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
     <label>Selected Month Invoice : </label>
     <div class='input-group date' id='invoice_date'></div>
 </div>`

`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#invoice_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'd-m-yy'
            });
        });
        $('#invoice_date').change(function () {
            var invoice_date = $('#invoice_date').val();
            // console.log(invoice_date);

            // Check date print in console.
            //  Write here ajax code for update date in database.
        });
</script>`

Thanks PHPanchal